# Prevent password reset urls from being redirected at login

Tags: users, redirection

I'm using the following code to redirect users at login (Drupal 6):

```
function hook_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
switch ($op) {
    case 'login':
        if (_cns_user($account)) {
            unset($_GET['destination']);
            unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
            drupal_goto('user/'. $account->uid .'/training', NULL, 'steps');
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that this doesn't allow for users to be redirected to the password reset page (user/reset/) when needed. Is there a way to prevent the reset url from being redirected? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to just test for the path, which you can get access to via `arg()`. Something like this would do the trick:

```
function hook_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'login':
      if (_cns_user($account) && !(arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == 'reset')) {
        unset($_GET['destination']);
        unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
        drupal_goto('user/'. $account->uid .'/training', NULL, 'steps');
      }
      break;
  }
}
```